# ExpressJS Mongoose render view after getting data from database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I need to render view after mongodb provide data from database. I write this code but the main problem is view is generated before getting data.

```
router.get('/', async(req, res, next)=> {
    try{
        const products = await Product.find({});
        res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Express',products });
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

});
```

Comment: try `Product.find({}).exec()`

Comment: Actually, the query object that `find` returns is a "thenable", so you shouldn't need to call `exec()` on it. You may just need to remove the `next` parameter from your handler so that it doesn't look like middleware to express.

Comment: Why don't you use the promise `Product.find({}, function(err, products){ res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Express',products })})`

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like this:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  Product.find({}, (err, items) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("An error occurred", err);
    } else {
      res.render("home", { items });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Using callbacks is not a great practice. Using async await is always better. You can write same code with less complexity using async await. Also you can handle errors easily with async await

Answer (score 0):

Actually everything looks great, idk why it's not working. I probably write something like this:

```js
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const products = await Product.find({});
    if (!products) return res.render("error");

    res.render("shop/index", {
        title: "Express",
        products
    });
});
```